# What is the difference between pages directory and routes in app directory in Next JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

A page route can be defined either as `/pages/my_page/index.js` or `/app/my_page/page.js`. What is the difference between them? Which one is preferred?

This is confusing for me because I can't use `getServerSideProps` in the app directory but I can in the pages directory. It does seem to me that both are by default sever side rendered components.

To be more specific, I want to do a fetch on a server component that takes the last slug from a path (ie capture c from `/path/a/b/c`) and returns to the client after the data has been captured. It seems I can only do this only if my page is under the pages directory. Making this change will cause a refactor in my code that I would rather avoid. The alternative is to make the page a client side component, which I believe is a way around the problem.

I tried to fetch an API from a server component that takes the last slug from a path, but I am not able to do this unless I move my page into the pages directory.

Answer (score 0):

I just learned that using the pages directory is an older pattern that Next js used. The solution to my problem is use the params that are passed down tot the component (more on that here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/patterns).

In short, I can just capture the params based on the definition of the route. If my page is under /posts/[user]/[postid], I can get postid by capturing it from the params passed into the component as such:

```
   import React from 'react';
   const Page = async ({params: {postid}}) => {
       console.log(postid)
    }
```